# How to upload files on ejabberd server?

Tags: ejabberd

I followed the documentation to and viewed multiple links to learn how to upload a file on the ejabberd server but still cannot upload files on the ejabberd server. My motive is to upload a file from android application before that I tried with the postman. I am using the default ejabberd configuration with a slite change by making tls **false** to use **http** not **https**.

```
hosts:
  - "faiqkhan-VirtualBox"

listen:
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: false
    request_handlers:
      "/upload": mod_http_upload

modules:
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: "http://@HOST@:5443/upload"
```

I am using like this: `http://faiqkhan-VirtualBox:5443/api/mod_http_upload` but getting `400 bad requests`
Did I miss something? Or do the whole thing wrong?

Comment: What did the upload request look like ? 
Does it match the XEP-0363 Specification ?
Did you request a slot first, before you send the HTTP Put Request ?

Maybe you want to have a look at the Specification: https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0363.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was missing to request slot.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration is correct but your URL is incorrect format.

```
 http://yourservername:5443/upload/
 or 
 https://yourservername:5443/upload/

in your case it will be,

http://faiqkhan-VirtualBox:5443/upload/
```

You should get 'Not found. from the server

/upload is the url parameter which is been specified in your
mod_http_upload module configuration

mod_http_upload is the module  that handle http file transfer or https file transfer if certificate is config

hope this is helpful

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30833209)